# Turn off bootstrap highlight validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, highlight

I'm using jquery with twitter bootstrap for layout. When i try to set input field type to 'email' to make it easier to be filled from mobile devices - field gets highlight:

[image]

The question is how can i turn it off?

Comment: do you have the jquery validation plugin added to the site and keyup validation enabled

Comment: It's not jQuery validation that is doing it... it's the browsers built in validation for input type email.   Bootstrap is leveraging the built in validation with CSS, It will stay red until a valid email is inputted

Comment: try adding the novalidate attribute to the corresponding form element. `<form novaidate>`

Comment: @ArunPJohny, noluck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether you are editing the `CSS` directly, or working on the `LESS` version,
However the code for that bit of hilighting is here:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/forms.less#L369

If you are editing the `CSS` directly, look for this block of code in the `CSS`:
[image: CSS Code]

Comment: Thank you `input:focus:invalid {
    color:#333;
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
}

input:focus:invalid:focus,
textarea:focus:invalid:focus,
select:focus:invalid:focus {
    border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}`   helped

Comment: Or you could just remove that block from the css :-)

Comment: i wasn't changing bootstrap's css. Ive overrided it.

Answer (score 2):

Try This: The first one removes the blue outline and the second one will remove the red outline.

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow:none !important;
  border:1px solid #ccc !important;
}
input:focus:invalid {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow:none !important;
  border:1px solid #ccc !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Force the css with inline style

```
<input type="text" style="border-color:#ccc;color:#333"/>
```

You can see other options with inspect element on that input.